# CI insert into database with default field if value is null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert into my database table.

I am getting this error from the column:

```
Column 'allow_edit_time_due' cannot be null
```

But, the column is set to default: '0'

How can I just insert into my table if 'allow_edit_time_due' is null, so that the value is the default value?

query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cal_tasks` (user_id, task, task_notes, task_type, allow_edit_time_due, task_time_due, user_created) VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($user_id) . ", " . $this->db->escape($data['task']) . ", " . @$this->db->escape($data['task_notes']) . ", " . @$this->db->escape($data['task_type']) . ", " . @$this->db->escape($data['allow_edit_time_due']) . ", " . $this->db->escape($data['task_time_due']) . ", " . @$this->db->escape($data['user_created']) . ")";
```

Comment: What does your insert look like?

Comment: In your $data, what does $data['allow_edit_time_due'] look like? If it's not been set, i.e. it's null then you're going to be trying to set it to null. Defaults only take effect when you don't specify the column. So, either remove the column from the insert (ok because it's got a default) or make sure that $data['allow_edit_time_due'] cannot be set to null.

Comment: I understand, thank you.  So, if I wanted to do this without supplying $data['allow_edit_time_due'] data, I would need a ton conditionals to modify the query?  I feel like there should be an easier way to do this without making my code look awful.

Comment: if you don't want to include your $data['allow_edit_time_due'] data then you could create an array with the values in, give the indexes the name of the column, the values be the values to put into the columns, and say if isset $data['allow_edit_time_due'] {$some_array['allow_edit_time_push'] => $data[allow_edit_time_push] then use the built in CI feature to update it  ($this->db->update('the table you are using', $some_array)} $data[allow_edit_time_due])}

Comment: go to phpmyadmin structure and set default of that column..

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, passing NULL value to the SQL would attempt to fill the column with value NULL, which would cause an error.

Anyway, using active record would help simplify your code (if preferable) in regard of this problem. All values would be escaped automatically, too.

This is an example:

```
$cal_task = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'task' => $data['task'],
    'task_notes' => $data['task_notes'],
    'task_type' => $data['task_type'],
    'task_time_due' => $data['task_time_due'],
    'user_created' => $data['user_created']
);

// optional, default if null
if (isset($data['allow_edit_time_due']))
{
    $cal_task['allow_edit_time_due'] = $data['allow_edit_time_due'];
}

$this->db->insert('cal_tasks', $cal_task);
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of our projects, we decided to migrate a reasonably large Firebird database to Postgres (several dragons encountered!).  Firebird allowed nulls on auto-generated primary keys and columns with default values, but PSQL does not.

We have many model methods that execute insert and update queries and these methods receive a populated payload object.  We needed a bulk solution to sanitize the payload just before executing the query. We didn't want to hack any drivers or core files for obvious reasons.

The solution that we are currently using is to set up a lookup array as a [config item](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html). The associative array of associative arrays has first level keys that hold table names, then the second level keys are the names of columns which do not accept `NULL` AND have `DEFAULT` or `GENERATED` values. The second level values are not used, but to offer clarity to the developer, we declared the default value.

```
$config['nonNullablesWithDefaults'] = [
    'first_table_name' => [
        'first_table_name_pk' => 'GENERATED PRIMARY KEY',
        'some_column' => 'N',
        'some_datetime_column' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    ],
    ...
];
```

Our MY_Model method/signature is something like:

```
protected function unsetNonNullablesWithDefaults(string $tableName, object $payload): object
{
    foreach ($this->nonNullablesWithDefaults[$tableName] ?? [] as $columnName => $defaultValue) {
        if (property_exists($payload, $columnName) && $payload->$columnName === null) {
            unset($payload->$columnName);
        }
    }
    return $payload;
}
```

If any of the columns in the payload hold a NULL value and are found in the lookup array, they are unset from the object before the object is returned.
All of our other model are extended from that model and therefore have access.

If you want a head start on programmatically creating the nested lookup array for non-nullable column, you can use the following, but I didn't quite bake the auto-generated primary keys into the PSQL query.

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(table_name, columns_json)) non_nullables_with_defaults_json
FROM (
  SELECT table_name,
         jsonb_object_agg(column_name, REGEXP_REPLACE(column_default, '^.*\''([^\'']+)\''.*$', '\1') ORDER BY column_name ASC) columns_json
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND is_nullable = 'NO'
        AND column_default IS NOT NULL
        AND table_name IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public')
  GROUP BY table_name
) subquery
```

Then just json decode that jsonb result and paste it into your `$config` declaration.